# Navigation to other web page using AJAX

Tags: php, html, ajax, authentication

I am making one login page.

If the user enters the **wrong** `user id and password`, then currently what happens is that it navigates to another page and there it is displaying **wrong user id or password** then redirecting back to the login page automatically.

Is there a way to show this message this without navigating away from the original page, using `AJAX` or some other method?

Comment: okk.. !! So what next.

Comment: Yep, it is, for sure!

Comment: POST username,password with AJAX ... return 1 or 0 from that PHP file, then when AJAX response comes, show error if response was 0, or navigate to the index page if response was 1

Comment: You fire an AJAX post request and then handle it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the redirect. You can just add on the ajax response function if response is empty to show a div that is hidden and reset the form. This is how it is done today. Redirects will decrease the load speed , will be annoying and its not a good method.

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: { 'user': user, 'pass': pass},
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                if(!data){
                    alert('message'); or $("your hidden div selector").show();
                }else{
                    redirect to what you need
                }
            }
        });
```